# App store app crash report

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, crash-reports

I got these crash report of my live app recently in XCode. I could not reproduce or trace the issue by myself. I have added the images of the crash report here. Somebody, please help me to point out the exact issue.

Screen 1
[image]

Screen 2 
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to insert a value into the mutable array at some index. Here inserting object might be nil or some issue with index. please check that

Comment: You should upload your apps symbols, so that the crash reports would show the actual class, method, filename and line number where you are doing something wrong instead of just memory addresses.